Who was Iscah in genesis
Iscah is Harans daughter yes, but Abram married his mothers nurses’ daughter who’s father is Terah. The book of Jasher 9-12 speak of these things

For future reference please include a biblical reference. This is neither here not there in this case as the question will be closed as a duplicate.
